# Is ASP.NET inherently more secure than other languages?

Tags: asp.net, security

A CEO told me recently that one reason a financial website of his was secure is because it was developed with ASP.NET.

Could there be any truth to his statement? Are there any features that make ASP.NET inherently more secure than other languages? Or are there features that promote secure programming practices better than other languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application is only as secure as the creators make it. Sure there are some features in asp.net, first one that comes to mind is that a text box will not allow html to be input (request validation). But this can be easily turned off be either necessity or a lazy programmer, and there are some lazy ones out there.

Sounds like that CEO probably just regurgitated some sales pitch someone used to sell him the application.